# ORDER BY em string date

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

Eu tenho uma tabela na base de dados, `novidades`, em que tenho uma coluna com o nome `date` está a ser armazenada como string no formato `dd-mm-yyyy`, mas eu gostaria de ordenar por data com base neste valor, calculo que tenha de converter em  `date/datetime` no momento do select.

O que estou a tentar fazer agora não é mais que isto:

```
Novidade::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
```

No entanto não resulta, a ordenação sai errada compreensívelmente.

**NOTA**: Eu não posso mexer na tabela e mudar o tipo de coluna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw) com a função do seu banco, por exemplo, para [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) utilize [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) para escrever a função de conversão de texto para data, ***exemplo***:

```
Novidade::orderByRaw("STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC")->get();
```

***Observação:*** o bom seria que o dado tivesse o campo no formato correto, ou seja, que fosse convertido para `date/datetime` eliminaria esse problema, porque, uma função terá custo maior na execucação da sua `SQL`.

<sup>**Referencias:**</sup>

- [$this orderByRaw(string $sql, array $bindings = [])](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw)
- [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Virgilio, desculpe, há alguma função semelhante? Deve ter a ver com versões mysql, porque em local dá-me o erro `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: STR_TO_DATE (SQL: select * from "novidades" where "novidades"."deleted_at" is null order by STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC)`. Mas em produção está tudo bem

Comment: @HulaHula essa SQL não é do postgresql? Qual é o seu Banco por favor?

Comment: É mysql em produção Virgilio, em local é sqlite, peço desculpa pela demora na resposta, mas só agora é que vi

Comment: @HulaHula então ta certo. concorda, outra coisa produção e desenvolvimento é cópia então bancos diferentes é um erro deveria ser tudo MySql! entendeu.

Comment: O erro só dá em local, com sqlite, a função não deve existir em sqlite com este nome. Mas sem problema, o que interessa é em prod mesmo